# Different object reference passed through Input doesn't fire pure pipe

Tags: angular, pipe, angular-changedetection

TL:DR; - Pure pipe not being triggered when new reference arrives, but it should. Any ideas?

We don't want to use ngOnChanges or DoCheck because we ended with a beautiful mess of sphagetti code before. Our use case is simple enough and we just want to be able to propagate the data to the whole DOM tree.

OnPush is not working, already tried it

---

We are refactoring our Angular app, which became big enough to be having enough bugs and problems because of the added complexity in events (and websockets events updating the data).

So we decided to create a data service for every main page of the application. It would store the state of that page and would be the go-to handle to handle any events any subcomponent might want to fire, as well as all websocket events that come from the connection

The problem is, we are having a lot of problems with data propagation. And that this is legacy code, so we don't want to change all the subcomponents so we need to do a data transformation for the Input the subcomponents require.

We already knew about how Angular can't detect changes in object's internals, but that was fixed really soon enough, by (poorly) making our dataService create new object references in each update, so we wouldn't have any kind of problems with Angular not detecting them

```
export interface ProjectData {
  list?: PageObject<Project>;
  active?: Project;
}

...
  private _state: ProjectData = {};
  private _stateSubject: BehaviorSubject<ProjectData> = new BehaviorSubject(this._state);
  public state$: Observable<ProjectData> = this._stateSubject.asObservable();
...

//We save the _state internally for checks on valid state updates (is the item active? is the item on the list?)
  requestList(options: QueryOptions) {
    this.projectService
      .list$(options)
      .pipe(
        map(page => {
          this._state.list = page;

          this._state = this.replicateState(this._state);

          return this._state;
        })
      )
      .subscribe(this._stateSubject);
  }

...
  // Use to force a new reference for the state object.
  // To be improved to actually make the logic work in an immutable way. For now, we want
  // to get this working, that's all.
  replicateState(oldState: ProjectData): ProjectData {
    return {
      list: oldState.list,
      active: oldState.active
    };
  }
```

Then, this state$ is retrieved by the main component of the page (aka, parent component). It will pass its data to every subcomponent. For the sake of this question, we are currently having problems with the table component, which lists the entities paginated.

```
<sv-table-v2
  [listPage]="(data$ | async).list"
  [headers]="headers$ | async"
  ...other inputs
></sv-table-v2>
```

And then, this sv-table-v2 has a component that renders the list. Although is from the old version and we didn't want to keep refactoring, so we wanted to make a transformation from our page to the Rows class that component uses in the input

```
 <sv-table-list
    #rows
    [loaded]="listPage"
    [rows]="listPage.data | createRows: headers"
    ...other inputs
  ></sv-table-list>
```

We had to create a pure pipe because we couldn't call a function in the template without it being called ad infinitum. Supposedly, the pipe caches the input and will only be refire whenever the input reference changes. But that's the case in this case and is not working.

We want to be able to propagate the data without having to delve in OnChanges or DoCheck. We feel them hacky unless you know quite well what to do with them, have a complex case to manage or have performance problems, which we don't have for anything other than passing inputs T_T. We also got a whole load of sphaguetti code before so we are trying to avoid it even tho a lot of answers try to hack this kind of stuff with those lifecycle methods

Really, we only want to be able to propagate the changes from the DataService to all the DOM tree. That's all.

We already tried OnPush strategy instead of piping, but its not working either. And, as far as I have read, we would still need for Angular to notice the reference did change.

Also: all this WORKS if we don't use the pipe. The data wont show on the table (because is the incorrect type), but the list will update it's size according to the page sizing we request, so we know the data could propagate correctly. That's why the pipe is our main suspect, is the only change.

Edit:

The code for the pipe, which i forgot

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { Resource } from 'src/app/core/models/resource';
import { ColumnHeader, Table } from 'src/app/core/models/table-data';

@Pipe({
  name: 'createRows'
})
export class CreateRowsPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(data: Resource[], headers: ColumnHeader[]): any {
    return new Table(data, headers).rows;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure without proper debugging your code, but you could use spread operator to notice the change in reference, hence try `return { ...oldState, list: oldState.list, active: oldState.active }` in your `replicateState` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, we found the solution way back, but I feel its hacky, specially because this practice was adopted from SO, as the correct way to have a subject subscribe to an observable to get all the events from them.

So:

```
  requestList(options: QueryOptions) {
    this.projectService
      .list$(options)
      .pipe(
        map(page => {
          this._state.list = page;

          this._state = this.replicateState(this._state);

          return this._state;
        })
      )
      .subscribe(this._stateSubject);
  }
```

This method and pipes will be called every time the method is called and the HTTP request is made, but the subscription won't be sending the new event (result from the HTTP request) to the this._stateSubject after an unknown event. Is like this._stateSubject just stops sending stuff.

But if you got the basic way, of sending it manually (what I was doing before I got the response in SO way ago)

```
  requestList(options: QueryOptions) {
    this.projectService
      .list$(options)
      .pipe(
        map(page => {
          this._state.list = page;

          this._state = this.replicateState(this._state);

          return this._state;
        })
      )
      .subscribe(state => this._stateSubject.next(state));
  }
```

Then the subject wont ever stop working, and will be sending any new http requests data that are made when we call this function.

Now that I'm writting this, I think the issue might lay in that, a subscription to a subject like that, who has the whole observable interface, might stop because the HTTP request sends a End signal, so the subject also ends after an unknown amount of time. But is something I realized while I was writting this and I'm not sure if that's the core issue.

TLDR: Just send it with next if you are having problems. I'm not sure on which is the underlying problem.